# Serialize an image in XAML using XamlWriter

Tags: wpf, xaml, serialization

I'm using XamlWriter to serialize a group of WPF objects. One of these objects is an Image control whose Source is set to a file on disk.

When the XamlWriter serializes the objects, it sets the source image to an Uri that points to the file on the filesystem. Is there a way to include that data in the Xaml so that instead of referencing the file, the information is stored in xaml?

Thanks

Comment: "include the data" as in serialize the binary data that's contained in the image?

Comment: exactly, thats just what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what I did in the end was build a wrapper class that used a binary serializer to store the images and the xaml code from the XamlWriter.

Comment: Cool; thanks! Did you base64 encode them as strings in the XAML file?

Comment: Thank you for the idea, @Carlos. So you stored the images together with the XAML file in a package? Or did you find a solution to store the binary data of the images with the XAML in a single file? Do you have a hint on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN:
[Serialization Limitations of XamlWriter.Save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms754193(v=vs.100).aspx)

"Images are also serialized as object references to images as they exist in the project, rather than as original source references, losing whatever filename or URI was originally referenced."